# saving a uploaded picture to a thumbnail and to base64_encoded string

Tags: php, html, file-upload, base64

OK, lets say we have a form and in it a simple file upload input

```
<form action="index.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image_file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit-btn" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

then comes the index.php file

```
// check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
if(!isset($_FILES['image_file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])){
        die('Image file is Missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
}

//uploaded file info we need to proceed
$image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
$image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size']; //file size
$image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp

$image_size_info    = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

if($image_size_info){
    $image_width        = $image_size_info[0]; //image width
    $image_height       = $image_size_info[1]; //image height
    $image_type         = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
}else{
    die("Make sure image file is valid!");
}
```

then I try to re-size the file

```
switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;   
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
    default:
        $image_res = false;
}
```

**Now I want to output the image to user's browser without to store the file.
This why I tried to do this**

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']));
```

**But I think here I have a failure in my logic, becaue it doesn't output the picture, anyway what I want in the end is to echo the picture like below.**

```
switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,"'.$data.' alt="" />'; break;
    case 'image/gif':
        echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,"'.$data.' alt="" />';break;
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"'.$data.' alt="" />';break;
    }
```

**Can someone see the failure ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of your double quote(`"`) here,

```
...
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,"'.$data.' alt="" />'; break;
                                      ^ your double quote here is wrong
```

It should be like this,

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$data.'" alt="" />'; break;
                                               ^ your double quote should be here
```

Plus I don't see any reason why you're using `imagecreatefromXXX()` functions, it doesn't make any difference to your logic.

**Based on your question:**

> ... want to transform the uploaded picture to a variable as a string or whatever and display it using `<img>` tag

Then your code should be like this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="index.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image_file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit-btn" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-btn'])){
    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
    if(!isset($_FILES['image_file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])){
            die('Image file is Missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
    }

    //uploaded file info
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp

    $image_size_info    = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

    if($image_size_info){
        $image_type = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
    }else{
        die("Make sure image file is valid!");
    } 

    $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_temp));
    switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$data.'" alt="" />'; break;
    case 'image/gif':
        echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.$data.'" alt="" />';break;
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$data.'" alt="" />';break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have encoded the file as below :

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']));
```

So you should output it like below:

```
switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,"'.$data.'" alt="" />'; break;
    case 'image/gif':
        echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,"'.$data.'" alt="" />';break;
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$data.'" alt="" />';break;
}
```

**There is no need to use decode function.**

Answer (score 1):

Set the content-type header and use **$image_res** with  `imagejpeg`, `imagegif` or `imagepng` as needed:

```
switch($image_type){

    case 'image/png':
      header('Content-Type: image/png');  
      imagepng($image_res);

    case 'image/gif':
      header('Content-Type: image/gif');
      imagegif($image_res);

    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($image_res);

}
```

The reason why it looks like in the screenshot you posted is because the headers can't be modified after sent to the browser. When your form is output, the headers are sent.

You can solve this by separating the form and the php logic in different pages:

> **index.php**
>
> ```
> <form action="process.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
> <input name="image_file" type="file" />
> <input type="submit" name="submit btn" value="Upload" />
> </form>
> ```

---

> **process.php**
>
> ```
> // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
> if (!isset($_FILES['image_file']) ||
>     !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])){
>       die('Image file is Missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
> }
>
> // uploaded file info we need to proceed
> $image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
> $image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size']; //file size
> $image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp
>
> $image_size_info    = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size
>
> if ($image_size_info) {
>     $image_width        = $image_size_info[0]; //image width
>     $image_height       = $image_size_info[1]; //image height
>     $image_type         = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
> }
> else {
>     die("Make sure image file is valid!");
> }
>
>
> switch ($image_type) {
>
>     case 'image/png':
>         $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);break;
>
>     case 'image/gif':
>         $image_res =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;
>
>     case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
>         $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
>
>     default:
>         $image_res = false; 
> }
>
> switch($image_type){
>
>     case 'image/png':
>       header('Content-Type: image/png');  
>       imagepng($image_res);
>
>     case 'image/gif':
>       header('Content-Type: image/gif');
>       imagegif($image_res);
>
>     case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
>       header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
>       imagejpeg($image_res);
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Your solution is not working I get `Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`